# Adding in links in Titles and Images with Custom Fields - WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-fields

So my question is I need to add a link to a image and header in my wordpress site. Now I have tried to just add it next to it but nothing happens. It is using Custom Field Plugin.

Here is what the code looks like

```
<div class="calloutboxes">
    <h2><?php echo $cbox['title']; ?></h2>
    <img src="<?php echo $cbox['image']['sizes']['gallery_large'] ?>" height="<?php echo $cbox['image']['sizes']['gallery_large-height'] ?>" width="<?php echo $cbox['image']['sizes']['gallery_large-width'] ?>" alt="<?php echo $cbox['title']; ?>" />
    <p>
        <?php echo $cbox['description']; ?>
    </p>
    <a title="Read more about <?php echo $cbox['title']; ?>" href="<?php   echo $cbox['read_more_url']; ?>"><i></i>Read More</a>
</div>
<?php endforeach;?>
</div>
</div>
```

Thanks

Comment: What does print_r($cbox) return?

Comment: cbox is the custom field. where would you like me to place print_r($cbox)

Comment: You can use pastebin and share the link.

Comment: Would it not be as simple as this to adding a link. http://pastebin.com/NYW0dubC Will take the link from my custom box called read_more_url  and make the image clickable?